# What is the best way to report this apparent bug re setting tikz font size in documentclass minimal?

Tags: tikz-pgf, bugs

I was using Overleaf to do drafts of various figures and was unable to set the font size. For example, this

```latex
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[font=\huge,left] {squash this bug};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives the error

```
l.5 \node[font=\huge] {
                       squash this bug};
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

It turns out that changing the document class from `minimal` to `article` solves the problem. Where/how should I report this? Thanks.

Comment: There is nothing really to report, the `minimal` class isn't suited for this since, as you have discovered, it does not define font sizes (and a lot of other stuff). Don't use it. The really "minimal" class for typesetting tests is `article`.

Comment: As @campa says, this isn't a bug. `minimal` is supposed to (not) work like this. It isn't intended for minimal working examples (or minimal non-working examples, for that matter). Use `article` or `standalone` for MWEs/MNWEs.

Comment: See [Why should the minimal class be avoided?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42114/82917)

Comment: Try changing font size without `tikz` to see that `tikz` is irrelevant here.